# Does a uniform circular disk make a perfect gravitational lens?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-lensing

I'm surprised at this.  I'm expecting to be corrected, but these are my back-of-the-envelope workings ...

Starting out with a cylindrical lens oriented along the line of sight. Assuming the cylinder has uniform mass density, $\rho$, and a diameter much smaller than its length which, in turn, is much smaller than the focal length, $D << L << f$, which means all the angles are very small. In the following, for points inside the cylinder, '$r$' denotes radial distance from the center of the cylinder.

Then $ g_r(r) = -G.\rho.2\pi r$ is the gravitational field inside the cylinder and  $\Phi(r) = G.\rho \pi r^2$ is the potential.

Integrating along the length of the cylinder (ignoring end effects), the deflection angle due to the field is

$\theta (r) = (g_r(r)/c^2)L = (G/c^2)(\rho.L.2\pi r)$

This gives a focal length $f = r/\theta (r) = 1/[(G/c^2)(\rho.L.2\pi)]$ which is independent of $r$.  *As it should be for a good lens*.

The additional time for the geometric path-length taken by a ray at radius $r$, is

$\Delta t_g(r) = {1 \over 2} (r^2/f)/c = (G/c^3).\rho.L.\pi r^2$

The transit time through the cylinder is $L/c$ and the delta time delay in the cylinder due to time dilation from the gravitational potential is

$\Delta t_c(r) = -(L/c)\Phi (r)/c^2 = -(G/c^3).\rho.L.\pi r^2$

So not only are the rays all focussed, but they all arrive at the same time, $\Delta t_g(r) + \Delta t_c(r) = 0 $. *As they should for a good lens*.

Since it doesn't matter very much where the mass is distributed (on the scale of L), we can double $L$ and halve $\rho$, for example. Or we can compress the cylinder into a flat disk with area density, $\rho L$.

Is this the right conclusion? A flat uniform circular disk will act as a 'perfect' gravitational lens?